# STOREDRV.Deliver.Exception:StoragePermanentException thrown when calling Office 365 Graph APIs

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-web-app

At my IT company, we've developed an application that interfaces with Microsoft Graph APIs in order to log in, read and write emails.
We are using some custom Open Extensions  (formerly known as Office 365 data extensions) that are needed to add properties needed for our business logic to Microsoft Graph's resources.

Here's an example message:

```
"message": {
      "subject": "TEST",
      "body": {
          "contentType": "html",
          "content": parsedBody.body
      },
      "toRecipients": to,
      "ccRecipients": cc,
      "bccRecipients": bcc,
      "attachments": [],
      "extensions": [
          {
              "@odata.type": "Microsoft.Graph.OpenTypeExtension",
              "extensionName": "it.brainwise.ecms",
              "ddpnode_id": "4", // custom business data
              "company_id": "44" // custom business data
          }
      ]
 }
```

While everything has worked properly in production for about a year, we're currently having issues in dealing with the email box of a single user (out of hundreds). Since last week, that single user isn't able to send emails that leverage the aforementioned custom extensions, and cannot even receive emails where the same extensions are implemented. This user is still able to send/receive basic emails with no extensions attached, though.

The returned error is the following:

`Remote Server returned '554 5.2.0 STOREDRV.Deliver.Exception:StoragePermanentException; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Invalid named property: [{e550b918-9859-47b9-8095-97e4e72f1926}:'IOpenTypedFacet.it.brainwise.ecms-684886'] . StoragePermanentException: Invalid named property: [{e550b918-9859-47b9-8095-97e4e72f1926}:'IOpenTypedFacet.it.brainwise.ecms-684886'] . [Stage: DeliverMessage]'`

No other user of our app has ever experienced a similar problem.
We've already reached out to the official support, with no results: they've asked us to ask a question on StackOverflow, so here we are.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Except the redirection, what is the other useful information from the support team? This may need the  product team's support. To get help from community, we guys which not from product team need more information.

Comment: Hi Seiya, what kind of other information do you need? We've tried to write down all information to the best of our knowledge. Maybe we're missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was this user originally on earlier versions of Exchange, like Exchange 2010?  It may have accumulated many custom named properties over time, and hit a limit.  I've read that one temporary solution may be to move the mailbox to a different database.

References:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/2ed3e05d-ee12-460f-b829-8fd6e8c235cf/exchange-2010-how-to-increase-the-named-properties-for-exchange-2010-mailbox?forum=exchangesvradminlegacy

https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1565d1ed-cb44-47c0-a407-164a5c562029/number-of-named-properties-reached-the-quota-limit-8192-on-exchange-2003?forum=technicalqueries

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't feasible for our use case, but thanks anyway